# Why the default value of automatic variable is 0 instead of garbage one?

Tags: c++, variables, c++11

Consider the code snippet:

```
int main()  
{
int n;
cout<<n;
float f;
cout.setf(ios_base::fixed,ios_base::floatfield);
cout<<endl<<f;
char ch;
cout<<endl<<static_cast<int>(ch);
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
0.000000
0
```

Why it is not set to the garbage value instead of zero? Is it the consequence of undefined behavior? Compiled with `g++4.8.2` on `Ubuntu 14.04`.

Comment: Zero is a perfectly valid "garbage" number, in any case it's undefined behaviour, your implementation could print "foobar" if it wanted to.

Comment: Would be hard to print "foobar" out of numbers though

Comment: Compile with `-O3` and you might get a differend result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a compiler- and option-specific effect.

Static variables are zero-initialized first of all. Automatic local variables have no such guaranteed initialization. But a compiler can add zero-initialization, just to be “helpful”.

You're accidentally right that for the presented code the 0 result is “the consequence of undefined behavior”. But that's only because using an indeterminate value of type `int` is undefined behavior, or at least was UB up till and including C++11. It's a bit unclear whether accessing an indeterminate value of one of the three basic `char` types is UB: there are some Defect Reports about it (DR [#240](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#240) and [#616](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#616)), and the C++14 wording is different from C++11 and earlier, and seems to have moved the specification of UB to some other part of the standard.

Answer (score 1):

You should remember that there is no default initial value for automatic variables defined in the C++11 standard.

In practice, such a variable would contain some garbage value (if it sits in a processor register, the previous value of it; if it sits in a slot of the call stack, the former value at that location) which could be 0 (or something else).

Details are implementation specific and would vary with the compiler, the run, the optimization flags.

Read about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), notably Lattner's blog: [What every programmer should know about undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html). Be really [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) of them.